# How to compute $\displaystyle\prod_{i = 1}^{\infty} \frac{x^{i}}{e^{i!}}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, infinite-product

In my text book it is stated (without any explanation) that
$$
\prod_{i = 1}^{\infty} \frac{x^{i}}{e^{i!}} = e^{e^x - 1}
$$
and I can't really think of how one can show this.

Comment: It should be $$
\prod\limits_{i = 1}^\infty  {e^{\frac{{x^i }}{{i!}}} } ,
$$ because then $$
\prod\limits_{i = 1}^\infty  {e^{\frac{{x^i }}{{i!}}} }  = e^{\sum_{i = 1}^\infty  {\frac{{x^i }}{{i!}}} }  = e^{e^x  - 1} .
$$ (use the identity $e^a e^b  = e^{a + b}$ an infinite number of times)

Comment: @Gary thanks! That's a typographical mistake in the book then

Comment: If you take logarithms,
$$ \log \prod_{i=1}^{\infty} e^{\frac{x^i}{i}} = \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \frac{x^i}{i!} = e^x -1$$

Comment: This is one very good reason to avoid vertically stacked fractions in exponents. I do wonder why @Gary chose to answer in the comment section.